# PHP version is not changing after write statement into bash-profile

Tags: php, bash, xampp

I tried to make the xampp php version as a default php instance. At the moment the build in php version is default. In the nano .bash_profile I write the statement

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
```

and this is no stored in the `bash_profil`. But when I check the php version via `php -v` I get the older one. Any idea?

Comment: did you restarted server (apache)? it's necessary to restart server to reflect changes

Comment: @AlivetoDie: It is definitely not needed to restart apache when running PHP from terminal...

Comment: @JiriHrazdil, if you add something to your `.bash_profile`, you either need to log in fresh or source your `.bash_profile` with the command `. .bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

`exec "$SHELL"` to load your recently changed .bash_profile. That should do it.